# Axios GET Request Progress Bar

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, axios

I am creating a Laravel App with Vue JS and Axios.
Does anyone know how to make progress bar or loading bar in AXIOS GET?? I found some topics in google but it all uses on Upload Progress Bar which is Axios Post Request. Maybe someone here knows how to make loading bar when using Axios Get.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not important do you user Axios.
If you want create process bar, you can user library PACE https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

Comment: i just import pace.js to my project and also css? i will look on this.

Comment: and i cant download themes